# Delay JSON Feed for jQuery Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I noticed if you setup an event source(ie you going to be doing AJAX requests to the server) and start clicking next month rapidly it will fire off a request for each month. So if I click rapidly to get 5 times 5 requests will go off.

How can I make it so it will only fire once the user stops clicking. I find that such a waste of resources and can cause errors.

Comment: I had never really thought about this before seeing it show up, but this question really appeals to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right about this and i Have already lodged an error with the development team about this.

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=920&can=1&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

The only way i can think of doing this for now is to use the viewDisaply event.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewDisplay/

And inside that viewDisapy event call the loading event

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/

The only way i can think now is todo a javascript setTimeout

```
var t=setTimeout( FUNCTION , TIME IN MS);
```

inside the timeout check is isLoading, and if true then set the timeout again.

Or just use setTimeout inside the viewDisplay function to 500ms/1second? to create the desired delayed effect you are looking for, and once it times out you can add the desired source using addEventSource
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/addEventSource/

There is another option that is built into the calendar.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/

This options tells the plug-in to cache all events. so if you click next/next/previous/previous. It only calls ajax twice. Because the previous two months are loaded and cached.

There is no such thing as isClicking :D because we do not  know if the user is going to click again or not.. :D so we only have to anticipate this by putting a setDelay if a user clicks the next month twice within 1 second.

So if somebody wants to go 6 months in advance they will quickly press the next buttons and we can detect that like this.

```
//global var

var clicks = 0;
var isClicking = false;

 //jquery on load and calender initialisation.

 loading: function(bool) { if (bool) 
            { 
                    clicks=0; //The source has loaded completely - user stopped clicking
                    }
            else 
            {
            //Still loading 
            }
        },


 viewDisplay: function(view) {
            click += 1; //user has clicked- and this will grow each time he clicks before the ajax finishes.
            if (click > 1) //Yea he is clicking and clicking.. so lets stop calling ajax.
            {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', '/diaryFeed.aspx' ); //Remove the source so it stops firing on each click
            setTimeout ( $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', '/diaryFeed.aspx' ); , 1000 ); //Add the source again and it will load and fire loading(true) and reset our click counter
            }

            //Handle other view changes like month/week and date changes
            },
```

Comment: Could you show me how this Loading event would look like with the timeout? Are we delaying the ajax request through the timeout? Also is there a way to monitor when the click stops. Like if 5 clicks happens or something like that only use one. As I am not sure if timer is the best way to go.

Comment: Right i actually noticed that you mean something else with your question. I know its not logical but try and click month/day/month/day/month/day several time quickly and see what happnes ;) Any way- today I will have some code to solve your and mine problem as I need to fix this issue on my sites

Comment: You would have to do something like this to detect if a user wants to advance/retard by several months. Otherwise use lazyFetching  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/  which will remember any data that was loaded and wont request ajax on months that are cached.  I have added some code to the original answer

Comment: @ppumkin -  do you have any examples of this working . . i am trying to do the same thing but i can't get your answer to work

Comment: Do you have a fiddle somewhere? or some code. My answer is purely example and wont just work by copy and past. fullcalendar if quite fragile. I can help but you need to setup some environment